# how to activate different wired profiles in Gnome3?

Tags: gnome, networking, network-manager

I can't find out how to activate different wired profiles through gnome3 network panel ($ gnome-control-center network); i created these profiles within nm-connection-editor?

...Or is there a way to recreate these directly within the new (frustrating) gnome3 network panel?

Thanks for any help.
Kind regards.

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/79975/70550), you add them using `nm-connection-editor` and then select one from the network panel (just like with wireless networks).

Answer (score 1):

The feature removed from gnome shell :(

The workaround is,

1. install gnome shell extension: App indicator support.
2. Run nm-applet (should run automatic when you login)
3. Customize the extension, where to show network manager applet, in
   panel or message tray

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this problem today.  The official way is:

[image: Network panel wired ethernet section screenshot]

That teeny tiny `+` that doesn't look like its part of the UI.  Hit that to add a new profile.