# Ensure a specific Wired network profile is activated after booting

Tags: networking, gnome

I know how to make [multiple LAN profiles](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21217/network-manager-create-multiple-lan-connection-configuration-for-the-same-wired?lq=1). Now the problem I have is that the computer always goes back to "eth0" or "Ifupdown eth0" after a re-boot. I have to put this computer in an automatic installation so that it always **selects a specific fixed-IP configuration upon boot** (into GNOME 3). I.e. I can do this manually in the network settings, but it won't remember this next time I boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can edit the file `/etc/network/interfaces`, according to [this documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Configuring_the_interface_manually).